# Azure CDN Caching Index.html

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn, azure-static-web-app

I have a custom domain pointing to a static webside using Azure CDN. After a deployment my website was no longer showing up. This was because and old version of index.html was being served from the CDN itself.

I fixed it by purging the CDN manually, but this is not ideal because I frequently update the files for this website  via a build process.

What is the best practice to avoid this outcome? Do I need to add a purge to the build process itself or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

- We must configure the `max-age` to control `Cache-Control` header.Azure CDN makes use of the header's duration value.
- Add Cache-Control header in index.html  -
  `public, no-cache`
- All Cache-Control directives are supported by Azure CDN Standard/Premium from Verizon and Azure CDN Standard from Microsoft.

In ***Azure Portal*** => Your ***Static Web App*** => ***Configuration*** => ***Application Settings***, ads the below settings
Set the `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION`  to Never and `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` to 0

Reference taken from [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-how-caching-works)

Please refer [Manage expiration of web content in Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-cloud-service-content) for more information